# images of datepicker from jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I am using jquery ui datepicker.But i have just copied n paseted the css n js files required to use the datepicker.

```
$("#birth_date").datepicker(
{
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: "1990:2050",
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

While applying it to textbox i do this and one change that i have done in the css is i have just changed the width of .ui-datepicker class

So now i am facing 2 problems

1 - .ui-state-disabled is getting applied making the next and previous div's images go in disabled form.

2 - when i hover on those buttons(next and prev) the image disappers.

so now please can anyone tell me how do get the css images required and why is the disabled class is getting applied.

**Please help**

Thanxs in advance..

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle example. it would help alot

Comment: but the problem is occuring when i am coping the file in my local machine .
it works fine if i directly use the links of the css

Comment: @btevfik can u please tell me about my first problem..

when is that class applied..
**please help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons might not have a href. Also, you can do a custom download of jquery-ui to only get the datepicker and dependencies (including css and images) at http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: **Thanks** the images issue is solved...
now can u please why or when is that .ui-state-disabled applied?

Comment: In this  jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LBY7g/  the datepicker prev and next do work by default. According to the source https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js .ui-state-disabled is applied when the target is not an input, but a div or span.